# Upgrading Django Version: Best Practice

Tags: python, django, dependencies, version, upgrade

I've pretty big code base written on Django 1.5, it's about time to upgrade to the newest version (1.11.2) as many stuff don't work well.

I'm wondering if it's best to upgrade step by step: 1.5->1.6->1.7...
or just jump to 1.11.2

what method should be better and make the (hard) process easier? as my project has many dependencies?

Also what are good practices to do? I'm using virtualenv and aware of this [Django article about upgrading](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/upgrade-version/)

Comment: I would recommend that you just read the change logs across the versions, and just upgrade all the way - Yes, there is value in incremental upgrades, but very tedious process given the significance of changes that the framework has gone through.

Answer (score 5):

The document you found (“[Upgrading Django to a newer version](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/howto/upgrade-version/)”) has a good guide.

- An important part, *before* upgrading, is to **have full branch coverage** by the automated test suite for your application, before upgrading.

  You want to be able to run a full automated test suite, see everything pass *and* know that [all branches are exercised by the test suite](https://docs.python.org/devguide/coverage.html).

  This means that when you break something by porting to the new Django version, you'll be able to see which parts of your app are not behaving correctly any more.
- Read about what changes you need to make by reading the [release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/releases/) and [deprecation timeline](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/internals/deprecation/), for all of the relevant releases between your current and target Django versions.
- See what dependencies you'll need to upgrade for Django; you might need to correct your code if it relies on incompatible features in an outdated third-party library.

**All** of those should be done before upgrading a single thing, in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on two things. How many people are using the Django app, and the extend of your test coverage.

If you are the only user, no worries, upgrade all the way. But if you have a lot of users you will quickly find out by upgrading all the way to 1.11.2 that some edge cases may not be covered by your tests.

Expect a lot of error 500 along the way.

If your coverage is close to 100% on all your apps, you may not have that problem.

Note that a lot has changed since 1.5.

Comment: its only for my use and has no tests :)

Comment: All the way it is :)

Answer (score 1):

I my case about: Data

I am using SQLite and i am sure that, the lastest version can kill you if you have only 1 conflict.

python manage.py makemigrations  and so on had so many chance in it's method.

And if you change Python from 2x to 3x, it is a new case too =))