# ImportError: cannot import name LoginService-After upgrading django1.3 to 1.11

Tags: django, importerror

I am upgrading my Django application from 1.3 to 1.11. There is an import `from erp.auth.backend import LoginService`.

This import works in Django 1.3, but after upgrading Django to 1.11 import doesn't works and raises

> 'ImportError: cannot import name LoginService'.

Comment: What was the erp version before and after upgrade ?

Comment: Try [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44378695/upgrading-django-version-best-practice/44380098#44380098), if it can help

Comment: this is most probably just a version issue. Try upgrading `erp`